# How to resize subplots in pyplot, dependent on the height of a table?

Tags: matplotlib

There are many ways in matplotlib.pyplot to change the size of subplots. However, they all seem to require some hand-tuning. I would like to do it in an automatic way, depending on the actual sizes of the plots.

In my case, I would like to generate a whole lot of pdf files that look something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the table in the top subplot has a lot of white space around it, so I would like to reduce the vertical size of the top subplot and make the bottom one larger, to fill up the space a bit better.

I know that I can set the sizes of subplots with `GridSpec`, among a bewildering array of other methods. However, the number of rows in my tables will vary from file to file, so I don't know in advance what sizes I want the subplots to be.

TL;DR: I want the first subplot to be as tall as the table (however tall that is) and the second to take up the remaining space. Is this possible in MatPlotLib?

Comment: There is no built in way to do this but it’s likely possible  if the table had a get_tightbbox method you can get the bounding box and adjust the position of the two axes based on the bounding box size of the table.  It’s a bit involved because you need to invert the transform from pixels to figure units to set the position but it’s not too hard.   You can look at the source code for tight layout or constrained layout for ideas.    But if you are only doing a few times, suggest maybe doing by hand.

Comment: Meh, I think this is actually not possible with `table`.  If you change the size of the axes the table is on, then the table changes size, and you get more white space.